# Scroll to Section/Row after [super viewDidLoad]

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to scroll to a position of a UITableView after the viewDidLoad...for example
scroll to section 2  row 4.

How I can do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried UITableView's -(void)scrollToRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath atScrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition animated:(BOOL)animated